# Worms (Tolaim) in dried fruit

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, fruits, tu-bishvat, bugs

With Tu B'Shevat in 2 weeks, and the Inyan of eating fruits many people eat dried fruit. What are the concerns regarding worms in specific fruits? How do you check to make sure that there are no unwelcome critters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Check the Star-K's guide to insect checking, appropriately named: http://www.checkforinsects.com/

2) Here is a Tu Bishvat guide for this year (5771), based on the sefer of R' Moshe Vaye: http://www.jerusalemkoshernews.com/wp-content/uploads/shvat_5771_english.pdf.